# Got warning after installed library pdfmake in angular version 7

Tags: angular, pdfmake

I got this warning after installed library npm install `pdfmake` in angular version 7, currently, it works fine but I need to fix it. I already try to use the old version and last version of that library but still the same you can see the warning in below:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/ng-pdf-make/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.js 25:25-41
"export '$$observable' (imported as 'symbolObservable') was not found in 'rxjs/symbol/observable'

WARNING in ./node_modules/ng-pdf-make/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js 71:15-36
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/ng-pdf-make/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js 87:15-102
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the rxjs version used by this module is 5.1.0. This does not use the `.pipe` operator. You got a couple options.

1. Create a bug card, which is also kinda [there](https://github.com/BennyFranco/ng-pdf-make/issues/13) and being ignored.
2. Create a fork from the repository, and update to the latest rxjs version. You probably need to do some code refactoring as well to make it work.
3. Try `npm i rxjs-compat`. This creates a compatibility layer between the two rxjs version. Not sure if that will work out of the box